# How to use Regular Expression with FindWindow?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, setfocus, findwindow

I am ultimately trying to write something that will check if a specific window exists, and set it as active in the event it is.
I was able to use FindWindow to find a literal windows name.

```
int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "121226-000377 - company -  Oracle RightNow CX Cloud Service");
            if (hWnd > 0) //If found
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
            }
```

The number at the front of the title changes and will never be the same twice, therefor I was trying to use Regular Expressions to find if any active window has the name structure as shown above but the numbers can change. I have a regular expresion that works for this, but I don't know how to implement it. I tried:

```
int hWnd = FindWindow(null, @"^\d+-\d+\s.*?RightNow CX");
            if (hWnd > 0) //If found
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
            }
```

But it continually fails. So how do I use the FindWindow/SetForegroundWindow commands while making them use the regular expression to check with?

UPDATE~~~~
I selected a best answer, but here is the actual code for how I got this to work in case anyone is interested.

```
   protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);

                Match match = Regex.Match(sb.ToString(), @"^\d+-\d+\s.*?RightNow CX",
               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


                // Here we check the Match instance.
                if (match.Success)
                {
                   ActivateRNT(sb.ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    //this gets triggered for every single failure
                }
                //do nothing


            }
            return true;
        }

private static void ActivateRNT(string rnt)
        {
            //Find the window, using the CORRECT Window Title, for example, Notepad

            int hWnd = FindWindow(null, rnt);
            if (hWnd > 0) //If found
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
            }

        }
```

I still need to figure out how to test in the EnumWindows method to throw an alert if the window needed doesn't exist, but I'll worry about that at a later time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [`EnumWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for, although I'm not 100% sure how you'd use it in C# as you'll need a callback.

Edit: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows) got some code including an example callback.
Edit 2: The linked [MSDN sample][3] has more details on why/how to do it that way.

Comment: I used EnumWindows() to check all active windows as explained in the link, and then checked them against my RegEx, and when one passed the RegEx test, I passed it by name to FindWindow and then set it as the active window. See Revised OP for my solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the process name of the window searched you could try with something like this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(pFoundWindow);
}
```

[MSDN on GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in function/method/API for searching for windows with a regular expression pattern.  One way of accomplishing it would be to enumerate the windows [such as with this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Enumerate-top-level-9aa9d7c1) and then compare the window text in the callback function using the regular expression.